# Converting cycles per byte to bytes per second?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I find that many algorithms in cryptography show performance in cpb (cycles per byte) but I need the throughput in MB/s for some modern representative cpu.

How can I convert from cpb to MB/s?

Comment: In future, please only ask one question per question. Your other question was vague (did not specify what OS, or programming language you wish to retrieve the information using), so I have edited it out.

Comment: you got `[cy / byte]`, a CPU comes with `[Hz] == [cy / sec]`, do the math...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: And here is the duplicate asked four years earlier: [Calculating cycles per byte](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3943/10496)